# Writing custom controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, presentation-layer, webusercontrol

HI Guys,
I'm interested writing a set of custom controls (most likely in ASP.NET), was wondering what sort of guidelines I should follow.
- Is there any generic requirements for UI controls that should be followed?
- When writing documentation / samples etc, any guidelines on what they should include?
I know it's very general question but interested in your feedback on how I should I begin and maybe have a set of tight guidelines/framework from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to start with a generic documentation of custom controls, for asp.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx

everything else will be a matter of what exactly are you tring to create :)